# Round to Significant Figures Not Decimal Places with PgfPlots

Tags: pgfplotstable

I want to render numbers using PgfPlotsTable, rounded to a specific precision using Significant Figures rather than Decimal Places, see https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Significant_figures#/Rounding_and_decimal_places

```
/pgf/number format/precision=x
```

rounds the numbers to x decimal places in the displayed number, while

```
/pgf/number format/relative*=b
```

depends on the magnitude of the number i.e. `relative*=2, precision=2`, would display 1563.7 as 1563, 599.2 as 599, 0.34 as 0, sf=2 would imply 1600, 600, 0.34.